# Problems in setting up GLFW in CodeBlocks

Tags: opengl, codeblocks, glfw

I downloaded GLFW 3.1.1 and followed a tutorial telling me to:

1. Drop glfw3.h into MinGW's include folder
2. Drop the contents of lib-mingw in the downloaded file into MinGW's lib folder
3. Run the test program that comes with GLFW

After doing this I kept running into an error that stopped me from even starting a new GLFW project as the wizard kept looking for `glfw.h` and `glfw.dll` when they're now `glfw3.h` and `glf3.dll` I edited the wizard and was finally able to get the new project open.

After that, I clicked build and run and the compiler asked if I was sure. When I clicked yes it continually asked me if I wanted to build and run. The debugger just gives me this and I'm not sure what I set up wrong.

```
-------------- Build: Debug in 112311 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -g -I"C:\Program Files\MinGW\include" -c "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folders\C++ Files\112311\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\main.o
Execution of 'mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -g -I"C:\Program Files\MinGW\include" -c "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folders\C++ Files\112311\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\main.o' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folders\C++ Files\112311' failed.

-------------- Run: Debug in 112311 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folders\C++ Files\112311\bin\Debug\112311.exe
```

i

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using the wizard for GLFW projects because it's for an outdated version of GLFW.

You should create a console application then go to `Project->Build Options`. Go to the `Linker settings` tab then add `glfw3`, `opengl32` and `gdi32`, then click OK.

You can now test if it worked by copying the sample code on the [GLFW website's documentation](http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html) page and pasting it in main.cpp, replacing everything and running the program.